# Fetching new checked in changes from a branch

Tags: git, branch

I have created a branch from master. Now there are two persons working on this branch including me. The other guy checked in changes from his end. I wanted to pull those changes. However, when I did "git pull" nothing happened. What should I use in this scenario to merge those changes into my current database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I used the following code.

```
git checkout origin/<branch>
```

This solved the issue.

Regards

Comment: For future reference, if you are on a branch *X*, and you want to be able to `git pull` from another branch *Y* (which may or may not be on origin), you can use the syntax `git branch --set-upstream-to=Y`.
So in your case   
`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch>`   
followed by  
`git pull --rebase`.
You can see which branches have upstreams set with   
`git branch -vv`